# How can I use the drop shadow filter on multiple paths on inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, drop-shadow

So, If I shift select all the images I want to create a shadow for, I get the following image:

[image]

A way around this would be to group the objects and cast a shadow over that, which produces the following:

[image]

Which is arguably better. But what I like about the first one, is that each arrow casts a shadow over the next. I would like to get something similar to the first image, without those weird box shadow effect.

Anyone know how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Flood dimensions and co-ordinates in the Filter Editor, and also adjust the Guassian blur.

Here's an example, beginning with a simple drop shadow

[image]

The settings I made in the above example are dependent on the size of the graphic, so you will have to adjust them for your own graphics. The idea behind it is to make the Flood larger than the blur and have it kind of centred, then you can adjust the Effect parameters of the Gaussian blur too, if necessary.

Comment: This is incredibly detailed and helpful. THANK YOU, stranger.